# Connection refused when doing telnet to windows machine

Tags: linux, windows, telnet, check-mk

I am doing telnet to windows host from Linux to list Check_mk_agent data. but its giving me following output.

```
[root@myhost ~]# telnet winhost 6556
Trying xxx.xx.xx.x...
telnet: connect to address xxx.xx.xx.x: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Am I missing anything to set up? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is the localhost or IPv4 loopback address. Check your hosts file/ nameservers. Also, before going ahead with the retry make sure you have enabled telnet service on your windows machine. Also note the service you are running and on which port (port 23 is the port that telnet runs on). The other obvious problem might be the Windows firewall, where the port 6556 (I'm guessing this is a customised port you are using) on the Windows machine you are trying to use is blocked. Good luck debugging! :-)

This is a related/similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393356/telnet-a-localhost

Answer (score 0):

`winhost` is resolving to your local machine, not the remote windows one.